# Better way of carrying user information android application

Tags: android, android-intent, user-data

I am developing an android app which requires user accounts. At the moment I am passing the username as an attachment with each new Intent as follows:

```
 Intent child = new Intent(Login.this, Child_Home.class);
    child.putExtra("username", username);
    startActivity(child);
```

And then reading it in in each new activity. However, I am aware that this in inefficient. Are there any other ways to do this? I only need the username as it is unique.

Answer (score 0):

I generally make a User class with a currentUser singleton.  In your case it may only have a username, but then you're set up well for expansion.  You can check for the not logged in case by checking if the currentUser is null.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11664886)

Comment: @Mike yes it does provide a answer- it tells a pattern to use. Please pay more attention when reviewing

Answer (score 0):

Use Sharedpreferances for store user information.

Here is Helper Class of Sharedreferances.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;

public class SharedPreference {

    private static SharedPreference   sharedPreference;
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "AOP_PREFS";
    public static final String PREFS_KEY = "AOP_PREFS_String";


    public static SharedPreference getInstance()
    {
        if (sharedPreference == null)
        {
            sharedPreference = new SharedPreference();
        }
        return sharedPreference;
    }

    public SharedPreference() {
        super();
    }

    public void save(Context context, String text , String Key) {
        SharedPreferences settings;
        Editor editor;

        //settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //1
        editor = settings.edit(); //2

        editor.putString(Key, text); //3

        editor.commit(); //4
    }

    public String getValue(Context context , String Key) {
        SharedPreferences settings;
        String text = "";
      //  settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        text = settings.getString(Key, "");
        return text;
    }

    public void clearSharedPreference(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences settings;
        Editor editor;

        //settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = settings.edit();

        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
    }

    public void removeValue(Context context , String value) {
        SharedPreferences settings;
        Editor editor;

        settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = settings.edit();

        editor.remove(value);
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

Copy this class.

You can store User Information Like this.

```
SharedPreference.getInstance().save(LoginScreen.this, Username , "Key_for_Username");
```

and you can get valu in whole application like this.

```
String Username = SharedPreference.getInstance().getValue(context,"Key_for_Username");
```

if you want to clear all value than

```
SharedPreference.getInstance().clearSharedPreference(ActivityContext);
```

if you want to remove perticular value than

```
SharedPreference.getInstance().removeValue(context , "key_value");
```

i hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Shared Preference to save login credential and other information. Below code will help you to understand how to use Shared Preference. Use this kind of class for storing data and you can access this data anywhere in application.

```
public class SessionLogin {

    SharedPreferences pref;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    Context context;
    int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

    private static final String PREF_NAME = "MyAppPref";
    private static final String IS_LOGIN = "IsLoggedIn";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";

    public SessionLogin(Context context){
        this.context = context;
        pref = this.context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = pref.edit();
    }

    public void createLoginSession(String name, String email){

        editor.putBoolean(IS_LOGIN, true);
        editor.putString(KEY_NAME, name);
        editor.putString(KEY_EMAIL, email);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public void checkLogin(){

        if(!this.isLoggedIn()){

            Intent i = new Intent(context, ActivityHome.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    }

    public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){

        HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
        user.put(KEY_NAME, pref.getString(KEY_NAME, null));
        user.put(KEY_EMAIL, pref.getString(KEY_EMAIL, null));
        return user;
    }

    public void logoutUser(){

        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();

        Intent i = new Intent(context, ActivitySignIn.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }

    public boolean isLoggedIn(){
        return pref.getBoolean(IS_LOGIN, false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create Singleton class like this and store username over there and then reuse that username any where in the app.

```
public class SharedInstance {

private static SharedInstance singleton = new SharedInstance( );
private String username;

/* A private Constructor prevents any other
 * class from instantiating.
 */
private SharedInstance(){ }

/* Static 'instance' method */
public static SharedInstance getInstance( ) {
    if (singleton == null){
        singleton = new SharedInstance();
    }
    return singleton;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return username;
}

public void setUserName(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

}
```

Now for setting the username data anywhere in the app

**SharedInstance.getInstance().setUserName(username);**

And for getting the username data anywhere in the app

**SharedInstance.getInstance().getUserName();**